# SOLIDWORKS VBA open drawing of active part

Tags: vba, solidworks

I simply need to open the drawing by using VBA of the active part. Drawing always has the exact same filename and location as the part. What I got is

```
Option Explicit


Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks

Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2

Dim swSelMgr As SldWorks.SelectionMgr

Dim swDocSpecification As SldWorks.DocumentSpecification

Dim sName As String

Dim longstatus As Long, longwarnings As Long



Sub main()

Set swApp = Application.SldWorks    
Set swDocSpecification = swApp.GetOpenDocSpec("C:\Users\Public\Documents\SOLIDWORKS\SOLIDWORKS 
2017\tutorial\AutoCAD\7550-021.slddrw")

sName = swDocSpecification.FileName

swDocSpecification.DocumentType = swDocDRAWING

swDocSpecification.ReadOnly = True

swDocSpecification.Silent = False

Set swModel = swApp.OpenDoc7(swDocSpecification)

longstatus = swDocSpecification.Error

longwarnings = swDocSpecification.Warning

End Sub
```

But it doesn't work probably because of the file location which may always be different depending on how the active part is named and where the active part is located.

Could someone please share a function to simply open the associated drawing of the part?

Comment: So basically, your question really is: "How can I make the filename variable depending on X"? `"C:\Users\Public\Documents\SOLIDWORKS\SOLIDWORKS 
2017\tutorial\AutoCAD\7550-021.slddrw"` - Is this `7550-021` the part that changes? Where does that information come from?

Comment: My question is how to literally make VBA code open an associated drawing of the part that's currently opened. That drawing shares the same filename and location as the active part. That location and part name may may vary from part to part.

Yes in that example I provided the filename is "7550-021".

Another part won't have that filename, obviously

Comment: Have you tried putting this text you want into a string variable yet? That would be step 1.

Comment: There is no "text I want". In solidworks there's a button to just open the drawing of the part and that function doesn't record as macros. So I wonder what's the function for it in VBA code. I figured out how to open a drawing just by locating teh exact thing not based on anything and that's not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub main()
    Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
    Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
    Dim swDraw As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
    Dim swDocSpecification As SldWorks.DocumentSpecification
    Dim FilePath As String
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
    If swModel Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Open an assembly or part": Exit Sub
    If swModel.GetType <> swDocumentTypes_e.swDocASSEMBLY And swModel.GetType <> swDocumentTypes_e.swDocPART Then MsgBox "Open an assembly or part": Exit Sub
    Set swDocSpecification = swApp.GetOpenDocSpec(swModel.GetPathName)
    FilePath = LCase(swModel.GetPathName)
    FilePath = Replace(FilePath, ".sldprt", ".slddrw")
    FilePath = Replace(FilePath, ".sldasm", ".slddrw")
    swDocSpecification.FileName = FilePath
    swDocSpecification.DocumentType = swDocumentTypes_e.swDocDRAWING
    swDocSpecification.ReadOnly = True
    swDocSpecification.Silent = True
    Set swDraw = swApp.OpenDoc7(swDocSpecification)
    swApp.ActivateDoc3 FilePath, False, swRebuildOnActivation_e.swRebuildActiveDoc, Empty
End Sub
```

Comment: Clean opening of a solidworks file